# How do I do a query for each item in an array in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm a bit stuck.
I have done a query in wordpress to get a list of taxonomy ids and they have been put into an array:

which outputs an array of ids:

```
 array
   (123,
   633,
   992);

global $wpdb;        
        $results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT meta_value FROM  `usermeta` WHERE  `meta_key` LIKE  'alertids'");      

        if(!empty($results)) {


                             echo $wpdb->get_results("SELECT name FROM  `terms` WHERE  `term_id` =$results");


                }else 
                        {
                             echo "<p>We couldn't find anything !</p>";      


                        }
```

How do I do a query for every item in the array $results on the terms table.
I tried a foreach loop but ended up confusing myself.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should get you started

```
<?php
$myarray = array(123,633,992);
global $wpdb;
$return = array();
foreach ($myarray as $item){        
    $results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT meta_value FROM  'usermeta' WHERE  'meta_key' LIKE  '".$item."'");      
    if(!empty($results)) {
         $return[] = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT name FROM  `terms` WHERE  `term_id` = '".$results."'");
    }else{
         return false;      
    }
} 
if($return){
    return $return;
} else {
    return false;   
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering my question.
I found it was much easier to just do a join in the database and call the rows I needed from that.I will post the solution.

Comment: Fair enough. That would be the other way.

Answer (score 0):

I found a much better solution was to do a join in the database and just get the values from the join.I don't know if this is the best way of doing it but it works well for me.

```
global $wpdb;        
        $results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT usermeta.umeta_id, usermeta.user_id, usermeta.meta_key, usermeta.meta_value, terms.term_id, terms.name
            FROM usermeta
            JOIN terms ON terms.term_id = usermeta.meta_value
            WHERE usermeta.meta_key =  'alert_ids'
            AND usermeta.user_id =$user_ID");

                            foreach($results as $row)

                            {
                               echo name;

                            }
```